# Problem with calling a module from another module

Tags: excel, vba, module

I am having trouble calling modules from other modules using VBA in excel 2016 on a mac.
In a workbook I have 2 modules:

```
Sub testsub()
    Call xchart(a, b, c)
    MsgBox a
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub xchart(a, b, c)
    a = b + c
End Sub
```

When I run the first module(testsub) I get a "Compile error. Expected variable or procedure not a module"
What am I doing wrong? I have used this construct elsewhere in other workbooks and sometimes it works without a problem, sometimes it gives the same compile error.

Comment: Your variables are not declared, nor are they given a value? Unless the a is a public variable, you won't see it given the value of b + c either. If you want to return the value of `xchart`, you could as well just use a function instead.

Comment: I just checked leaving out my Option Explicit and it still runs without issue, when they're both in ThisWorkbook and in their separate modules. Where are yours located?

Comment: Leaving out `Option Explicit` means you can use variables without declaring them first allowing you to make spelling mistakes and spend days trying to find the error.  When variables are used this way they are given a default value numbers to 0, text to "", objects to nothing I guess.

Answer (score 2):

### Calling a Procedure

- In VBA, 'those' and 'these' are called *Procedures*, and they are located in *Modules*.
- Basically, a *Sub* does something while a *Function* returns a result.
- The *Call* keyword is considered deprecated.
- For whole numbers (integers(math)), you could use something like the following.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MyFirstCallingProcedure()

    Dim b As Long: b = 1
    Dim c As Long: c = 2
    
    Dim a As Long: a = SumupTwoIntegers(b, c)
    
    MsgBox a
    
End Sub

Function SumupTwoIntegers(ByVal Int1 As Long, ByVal Int2 As Long) As Long
    SumupTwoIntegers = Int1 + Int2
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the module name is the same with the Sub in the same module.

```
'check and RENAME THE MODULE containing this Sub if have the same name
Sub testsub()  
    Call xchart(a, b, c)
    MsgBox a
End Sub

'check and RENAME THE MODULE containing this Sub if have the same name
Sub xchart(a, b, c)
    a = b + c
End Sub
```